# Are python bindings for OpenCV 2.4.3 available?

Tags: 12.04, opencv, python3

I have installed the Libraries and files for OpenCV 2.4.3. However, the Software Center lists just the python bindings for OpenCV2.3. Where do i get the python bindings for 2.4.3 ? How do i install it ?

I have 12.04 64bit and i use Python 3.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV 2.4 is orginial proposed for Raring (13.04) and the same is backported for previous version.

You can download the python bindings for OpenCV 2.4 from here

- [python-opencv_2.4.2+dfsg-0exp2ubuntu1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~gijzelaar/+archive/opencv2.4/+files/python-opencv_2.4.2%2Bdfsg-0exp2ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
- [python-opencv_2.4.2+dfsg-0exp2ubuntu1_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/~gijzelaar/+archive/opencv2.4/+files/python-opencv_2.4.2%2Bdfsg-0exp2ubuntu1_i386.deb)

But make sure you have met the dependencies mentioned [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/python-opencv/2.4.2+dfsg-0exp2ubuntu1)

I am not sure whether OpenCV2.4 will work well with Python 3.2.3. You can try your luck.

Comment: Finally, i have given up. The packages (raring) are creating too many conflicts.